# Why does the thread synchronization not work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-ce

I have written a multithreaded program, in which three threads are trying to save the text to the same file. I applied the critical section. And under windows 7 works perfectly but in CE 6.0 does not sync, ie, each thread is trying at the same time to save:

**It works now!!! Thanks Everyone for help!**

[image: Emulator]

[image: Kernel tracker]

Critical section:

```
InitializeCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

// Create worker threads
for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
{
    aThread[i] = CreateThread( NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) WriteToFile, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);

    if( aThread[i] == NULL )
    {
        printf("CreateThread error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
}

// Wait for all threads to terminate
for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
{
    WaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(aThread[i], INFINITE);

    switch(WaitResult)
    {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            printf("Thread %d has terminated...\n", i);
         break;

         // Time out
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            printf("The waiting is timed out...\n");
            break;

        // Return value is invalid.
        default:
            printf("Waiting failed, error %d...\n", GetLastError());
            ExitProcess(0);
    }
}

// Close thread handles
for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
    CloseHandle(aThread[i]);

// Release resources used by the critical section object.
DeleteCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
```

Function called by a thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI WriteToFile( LPVOID lpParam )
{ 
// lpParam not used in this example
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpParam);

DWORD dwCount=1, dwWaitResult; 

HANDLE hFile; 
char DataBuffer[30];
DWORD dwBytesToWrite;
DWORD dwBytesWritten;

// Request ownership of the critical section.
EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

    // Write to the file
    printf("Thread %d writing to file...\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("file.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); 

    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_END);

    while( dwCount <= 3 )
    {
        sprintf(DataBuffer, "Theard %d writing %d\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), dwCount);
        dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);

        WriteFile( hFile, DataBuffer, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

            printf("Theard %d wrote %d successfully.\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), dwCount);
            }
        }

        dwCount++;
    }

CloseHandle(hFile);             

// Release ownership of the critical section.
LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

return TRUE; 
}
```

Comment: How did you initialize ghCriticalSection? Please post the code for that. Thanks!

Comment: I have: CRITICAL_SECTION ghCriticalSection;

Comment: Maybe the code is good but I not added something when I building a Windows CE image?

Comment: Ok, so when applied DeleteCriticalSection()?

Comment: As the documentation says, `DeleteCriticalSection()` invalidates the critical section object, which can no longer be used in calls to `EnterCriticalSection()` and `LeaveCriticalSection()` (unless re-initialized).  So, the correct answer to "when should you call `DeleteCriticalSection()`" is: after both threads are guaranteed not to use the critical section anymore.  If one thread waits for another to complete, then after the join is a good place to start.

Comment: _The Hungarian for hThread is wrong too._ - I borrowed it from Microsoft's example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Rafa Considering that your posted link not once uses `hThread` but instead the correct `aThread` I seriously dobut that.

Comment: @Hans Passant Bingo, Thanks!:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `TRUE` to the `fWaitAll` flag for `WaitForMultipleObjects`. On Windows CE, this is not supported: the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915354.aspx) says that this flag must be `FALSE`. `WaitForMultipleObjects` is thus not waiting, but returning an error instead, but you are not checking the return code. The main thread thus goes straight through, closes the handles and deletes the critical section whilst the "worker" threads are still running. Once `DeleteCriticalSection` has been called, the critical section "can no longer be used for synchronization", so the `EnterCriticalSection` calls probably no longer block, and you end up with the scenario you have here.

On Windows 7, everything works because the `WaitForMultipleObjects` call does indeed wait for all the threads to finish.

Rather than using `WaitForMultipleObjects`, just use `WaitForSingleObject` in a loop to wait for each thread in turn.

Comment: Bingo.  He's not checking the result of his WaitForMultipleObjects, which would inform him there's an error.  In CE it can wait for any, it can't wait for all.